# How does US Army Maj. Gen. Paul Eaton (ret) get to a "Look, you're attacking NATO... and we're going to consider our options to attack" scenario?

Tags: russian-federation, armed-conflict, ukraine, nato

In CNN's April 5 2022 ['The Russians are gone': What this image says about Russia's strategy](https://youtu.be/E-RYMDXL7kU?t=226) after about 03;26 US Army Maj. Gen. (ret) [Paul Eaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Eaton) says (my best-effort transcription, there are no closed-captions available at this time):

> **Eaton:** We need to prioritize the effort we have. Odessa needs to be our main effort, if we loose Odessa, that is a significant blow economically to the Ukrainian people, and we've got to deny that.
>
> We need to see more activity from NATO's naval forces...
>
> **CNN:** Out here in the Black Sea? NATO forces out in the Black Sea?
>
> **Eaton:** Absolutely. Absolutely. And a clear threat to Mr. Putin there; open up something else for him to consider in Kaliningrad - outside the port city of Kaliningrad where he keeps his Baltic Fleet. A little bit more aggressive...
>
> A lot of us though we need to present multiple problems to President Putin, but the first is the Black Sea, where I have seen reports that the Russians are laying mines outside of Bulgaria, and this is opening up an opportunity to say "Look, you're attacking NATO, and we are moving NATO forces - naval forces, and we're going to consider our options to attack."

**Question:** How does Eaton get from (the possibility of) Russian mines in the Black Sea outside of Bulgaria to moving in NATO naval forces to "you're attacking NATO" and subsequently NATO's "options to attack"?

Presumably there must be some logic and/or military strategy behind Eaton's proposal based on the facts of the situation. "A lot of us though we need to present multiple problems to President Putin" potentially refers to a group of retired military experts, but I can't be sure about that.

But to me it seems the idea is to drive NATO naval vessels into a known minefield and then complain about it. Am I missing something?

Comment: He may mean threatening instead of attacking. Or maybe it's just wishful thinking on his part. One should keep in mind that he seems to be retired, so not such an important voice maybe.

Comment: @Trilarion Retired yet notable military figures have recently becoming a quite significant voice in US discourse on both military and occasional political issues, (yes, as well as paid commentators for news outlets) so I think that retired ≠ unimportant.

Comment: @Trilarion to that end I've just asked [Have retired top US military officials become substantially more outspoken on political issues in the last decade?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/72360/16047)

Comment: While we can’t really know what he meant at that moment, what I think he’s saying is that the US needs to be more aggressive in contesting the Black Sea. If Russia is mining the area, then it would restrict NATOs future options if need be. Instead, NATO should assert their right to access those waters. Clearly the US navy isn’t going to drive into a minefield, but if that gets established it will slow down and complicate any NATO response that might happen in the future. But that’s just speculation from a random guy on the internet without access to classified intel

Comment: I don't think that even him knows what he's talking about, how are we supposed to guess? I'm voting to close this question as unanswerable. We can't read his mind.

Comment: "retired ≠ unimportant" I would say yes it equals. Retired means zero influence on actual things. Also there might be more Major Generals than you think. The more there are the less important.

Comment: There is a list of active Maj. Gen. of the US army on Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_active_duty_United_States_Army_major_generals) and I tried to count them but it got boring at 100 and I was approximately half way through the list. More or less the conclusion would be that there must be hundreds of them and hundreds retired ones more all with different personal opinions. One should not put too much weight on what one of them says. Doesn't mean there is a good question here, only to put things into perspective.

Comment: @Trilarion Hey, maybe if a shooting war with Russia does start, there might be a chance for some of them to come out of retirement and relive their glory days... If KGB officers can do it, why not US generals?

Comment: [Help understanding the down voting on these two questions and the (hopefully temporary) closing of one](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6232/16047)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You quoted

> where I have seen reports that the Russians are laying mines outside of Bulgaria,

That would be an attack if it is an attempt at a naval blockade of Bulgaria.

Comment: Kudos for posting a quite reasonable and well-received answer before the question was shut down and the posting of answers prevented because five people thought it couldn't be properly answered. [Navy ‘on alert’ against sea mines in Black Sea](https://www.ukrinform.net/rubric-ato/3434114-russia-mines-sea-routes-from-bosphorus-to-odesa-blames-ukraine-media.html) and [Russia warns that Ukraine has mined shipping lanes in the western part of the Black Sea. Somehow, Russia was able to state the number of mines laid, which only those laying them can know.](https://euagenda.eu/news/670237)

Comment: There's also [this twitter chain](https://twitter.com/StateOfUkraine/status/1505114769904345089) which I'm not qualified to judge, where there are suggestions of trapped ships and shelling.

Comment: [UN to work on safe corridor for ships stranded by Ukraine conflict](https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/un-work-safe-corridor-ships-stranded-by-ukraine-conflict-2022-03-12/) and [Ships stranded in Ukraine as conflict slows UN rescue efforts](https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/ships-stranded-ukraine-conflict-slows-un-rescue-efforts-2022-03-29/)

Comment: @uhoh, I somewhat agree with the closure. I expected it to happen, and I wanted to point out that reading the quote closely contains the answer. Unfortunately the comment function doesn't allow enough formatting.

Comment: I'm still unable to understand why so many (most) questions of the form [Why did...?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/search?q=why+did+is%3Aquestion) are not closed even though answers forward theories and unless they were inside the heads of the decision makers simply can not point to a single explanation and say "this is definitely the reason(s)", so as long as the explanations are *plausible* they are upvoted and the question is left open, and yet my question about a retired major general's view on a mine field is closed. I'm just really curious, seems like a dual standard. Any thoughts?

Comment: @uhoh, your question is *explicitly* asking what a single individual was thinking and  we cannot look into his head. Many other questions ask e.g. about a government's stated position, or the scope of customary international law.

Comment: I understand the wording [can be taken that way](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6233/16047) but it's not like a game of chess here; there are standard working definitions of what is an "act of war" and rough maps of the mine field in the Black Sea and which NATO countries are blocked by it are available. Since Eaton can be considered to have a good grasp of the fundamentals, it should not be so challenging *in this particular case* to see how anyone (not just Eaton) would reach the same conclusion.

Comment: So "how does X get to Y" is not the same as "what is X thinking?" but I can see how some folks would take it that way and I'll adjust my wording in future questions accordingly. In this case perhaps some form of asking if this mining can be considered an "act of war" or an "attack" on NATO or something similar.

Comment: @uhoh, the question when mining in international waters is an act of war seems relevant to me. But it would be important to sort out if this is a question on the law or about the facts of who mined where.

Comment: Perhaps the question is asked a little early then for a quick-closing community like this. Questions focusing on *verification* of the locations of the mines exclusively might be better in Skeptics SE than here. In some communities imminent answers are not a prerequisite for a question's survival (e.g. [What's best to do about questions that might not be answerable for a few months?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1407/12102)) but in the rough-and-tumble world of Politics SE with so many with their finger on the vtc button, if some folks can't at least imagine an instant answer...

Comment: the alternative is instant close. These are good lessons I can take away for future asking. "...it would be important to sort out if this is a question on the law or about the facts of who mined where." Yes. It would have been better if I'd referenced Eaton's comment as background, motivation and context only, (what brought me to wonder about this) and simply asked about mining as an act of war. In some sites like Math SE and History SE one can see questions *that require* well-developed answers that connect the dots in several steps, but here those might also be closed as unclear/multiple

Answer (score 5):

Turkey is a NATO member.  Why wouldn't NATO have naval assets in the Black Sea?  And, of course, if any Russian mines damage any NATO vessels off of the coast of a NATO country, that would be an attack on NATO.  Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: If NATO decides to treat it as an attack - since it may lead to a major (even nuclear) war. E.g., after [2015 Russian Sukhoi Su-24 shootdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015_Russian_Sukhoi_Su-24_shootdown) Turkey and Russia decided not to start a war over it: *On 25 November, the foreign ministers of Russia and Turkey spoke for an hour by telephone, and both governments stated that day that they would not initiate a war as a result of the incident.*

Comment: @RogerVadim that was still an attack by a Russian plane against Turkey.  The plane [was 1.36 miles inside of Turkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015_Russian_Sukhoi_Su-24_shootdown).  The fact that Turkey agreed to treat it as an accident was more a result of Turkey's judgement that it was an accident than a decision to look the other way.  If mines get deployed within Turkey's territorial waters, then there would be little doubt that it would be a result of *deliberate*, rather than accidental actions.

Comment: *If mines get deployed within Turkey's territorial waters*  - This is not the situation discussed here - *territotial waters* are only 12 nautical miles from the coast.

Comment: @RogerVadim I don't see why it's not what's discussed here.  Other than maybe adding Bulgaria to the answer.  Both Bulgaria and Turkey are NATO members.  And if Odessa is what's being discussed here, then really Romania being a NATO member is what's even more important.  That's 3 NATO countries which are on the Black Sea.

Comment: Because it is not the *territorial waters* that are mined.

Comment: @RogerVadim How do you get that from the quote though?  All it says is "outside of Bulgaria."  It's also my understanding that mines drift.  And if they are laid in such a way that a significant number of them is likely to shift towards the coast, the mines could drift into territorial waters.